# Creating a shortcut for runas /netonly and vsvarsall.bat . What are the quoting rules to use?

Tags: tfs, dns, dos

I am attempting to create a shortcut that will load the vcvarsall.bat (Visual Studio Command prompt) under a runas command. Specifically, I want a shortcut that starts in a specific folder; has the runas network credential set to a domain account; mains local account affinity; and has msbuild environment variables set correctly.

Background: We have team city build agents that are not on the domain. Occasionally, I need to troubleshoot them. This means running the build under the team city local account, getting from source using the domain account. I also have the same scenario when working from home - my home computer is not on the domain.

I can use runas.exe to get the credentials correct, but I don't get the msbuild environment variables.

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\runas.exe /netonly /user:domain\teamcityagent "%comspec% /k
```

If I load the environment variables as per the shortcut and set the start in folder, I get the environment variables and working folder, but I have to enter my credentials each tfs command.

```
%comspec% /k ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" x86
```

How can I combine these two into one shortcut? What are the command quoting rules that apply here? Can you concatenate commands in a shortcut? It would be coolest to do this without a batch file, but if I have to fall back on a batch file, I'll do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can execute multiple separate commands using `&&`.  Successive commands will only be executed if the previous one succeeds (i.e., errorlevel 0).  If you want to force all commands to execute, just use a single `&`.

e.g., printing "foo" and "bar" then pause

```
%comspec% /c echo foo && echo bar && pause
```

However in your case, when using `runas`, you need to wrap the entire command and command arguments in double quotes.  Any double quotes in the arguments need to be escaped by a backslash.  Other backslashes should be interpreted correctly without needing escaping.  To run as another user with the variables loaded printing a greeting, you can do the following:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\runas.exe /netonly /user:domain\teamcityagent "%comspec% /k \"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat\" x86 && echo Hello %USERDOMAIN%\%USERNAME%"
```

Comment: Cool! The backslash escape character was what I needed. The start in property of the shortcut is not respected when using runas - I land in "C:\WINDOWS\system32". The && saved me here: %SystemRoot%\system32\runas.exe /netonly /user:domain\teamcityagent "%comspec% /k \"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat\" x86 && D: && cd D:\TeamCity-MappedWorkspaces\